# Django REST API 'get' function

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). I have come across this:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
      instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
      instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
      instance.linenos = validated_data.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
      instance.language = validated_data.get('language', instance.language)
      instance.style = validated_data.get('style', instance.style)
      instance.save()
      return instance
```

This is probably a very simple question, but what is `get` function here? I'm having trouble finding any documentation about what it is. I understand that there is a `get` query function, but are these the same functions?

Comment: get is a dictionary method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`validated_data` is an `OrderedDict` and `OrderedDict.get(key, default)` is the method that fetches the `value` for the given key, returning the `default` if the key is missing from the dict.

In other words:
`instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)` will try to fetch `title` from validated_data but will return the current `instance.title` if the `title` key is not present in the validated data.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Answer (score 2):

get has nothing to do with the REST API.

validated_data is a dictionary. You can extract the value from the dictionary in the following ways.

```
d = some_dictionary

**Method 1:** a = d[key]
**Method 2:** a = d.get(key,custom_value)
```

In **Method 1**, a is assigned a value if key is present in the dictionary d. If key is not present, **KeyError** is raised.

In `Method 2`, a is assigned the value of d[key] if key is present in the dictionary else it is assigned the `custom_value`. The `custom_value` by default is None. Thus, an exception will not be raised even of the dictionary does not contain the key you are looking for.

In short, **Method 2** is the safe method for accessing keys of a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

`get` is a dictionary method.
You pass it a key and it returns the value associated with the key.
Optionally, you can also pass it the value you want it to return in case the key is missing from the dictionary. It is not necessary to specify a default value (it returns None is the key is not there), but it makes things clearer, even when you want None.

For example:

```
d={'ciao':1, 'how':2, 'are':3, 'you':4}
my_val = d.get('how', 10)
print 'my_val =', my_val
```

outputs

```
my_val = 2
```

whereas

```
my_val = d.get('absent', 10)
print 'my_val =', my_val
```

outputs

```
my_val = 10
```