# What is the purpose of sending instance.title as second argument in validated_data.get function in DRF serializer update function

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.author = validated_data.get('author', instance.author)
    instance.date = validated_data.get('date', instance.date)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

What is the purpose of sharing instance.title etc in second argument of "validated_data.get" function 
instance.title = validated_data.get('title', **instance.title**)

Comment: The same purpose as author and date? You basically appending the instance with title, author etc values

Comment: Yes same purpose for author and date. I want to know why we are sending instance attributes as second argument in the validate_data.get() function

Comment: `validated_data` is a `dict`, and `get` method accepts second argument as a default value if it doesn't have the specified key, so in case if you didn't send the `title` in your request body, the object's `title` will stay the same in stead of changing to `None`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.save()` method two things can happen, either it will create a new instance or update the existing instance depending on your parameter while instantiating the serializer class.

```
data = {“title”: ''TEACH YOURSELF C”, “author”: “Herbert Schildt”, “date”: “2013-2014”}
```

Suppose you wanted to create a new instance of the above data then you will instantiate the serializer class like this:

```
 book = Book(data=data)
 book.save()
```

But after sometimes you realized that you enlisted the wrong book of Herbert Schildt and you wanted to update the data with the right one. So now the previous data where you’d made mistake is the instance that you wanted to update with the correct one. So here,

```
instance = {“title”: ''TEACH YOURSELF C”, “author”: “Herbert Schildt”, “date”: “2013-2014”}


data  = {“title”: ''Java the complete reference”, “date”: “2016-2017”}
```

Now when you instantiate the serializer class you have to pass two parameters one is the instance and another is the data.

```
book = Book(instance, data=data)
book.save()
```

Now this time it will enter into the update method and update the existing data of the previously created instance with new data.
Your updated data stored in an ordered dictionary `validated_data`, when `instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)` executed it will check in the `validated_data` dictionary if there is any value present regarding this key “title”, as your data contains title key value then instance. title value is now  ''Java the complete reference”.

But when `instance.author = validated_data.get('author', instance.author)` will be executed, it will not find any value in the `validated_data` dictionary with the key “author”,then it will by default assign the value of the `instance.author` that means “Herbert Schildt”, as you have passed value in the argument `validated_data.get('author', instance.author)`.

Read these reference links if you have still confused:

1. [Django REST API 'get' function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30719117/)
2. https://testdriven.io/blog/drf-serializers/